# HTTP Response changed?

Tags: post, httpwebrequest, http-post, httpwebresponse

i have an `HttpWebRequest` that do 'POST' to a web server and get an HTML page In response.

I've been asked how is the best practice to know that the response i got has been changed or not?

I can't relay on the web server headers, they don't have to be.

this will increase performance in a way that i wont be need to parse the response over again and will go to the next request in a half of a sec or so.

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your webserver about last modification date. see [here](http://freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1945/58.htm). If you can't rely on that you have to parse your response anyway. You could do that quickly using md5. So you "md5" your current response and compare it with the previous.

Comment: This won't (or at least shouldn't).. Work on a `POST` request.

Comment: yes you're right. So you either have to change it to a GET or use md5 to compare it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be attempting to rely on the headers for a `POST` request, as it shouldn't emit any caching headers anyway.

What you need to do instead is perform a hash/checksum (this can either be `CRC(32)` for absolute performance or a "real" hash such as `md5`) on the returned **content** (this means, everything underneath the `\r\n\r\n` in the headers) and do a comparison that way.

It should be good enough to store the last request's checksum/hash and compare against that.

For example (psuedo):

```
int lastChecksum = 0;
bool hasChanged() {
    performWebRequest();
    string content = stripHeaders();
    int checksum = crc32string(content);
    if(checksum != lastChecksum) {
        lastChecksum = checksum;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```